# Collapsing numeric values

Tags: r, variables

I have two variables with the following levels: 1, 2, and 3. I averaged them together so now the levels are:

Levels: 0 < .5 < 1 < 1.5 < 2 < 2.5 < 3

However, I need to collapse .5 with 1, 1.5 with 2, and 2.5 with 3. Would the easiest solution bet to use factor recode? The syntax does not appear to make sense to me.

Comment: I'm very new to R. I will try these suggestions. Please do not interpret my lack of doing these to be disrespect.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have an ordered factor.

```
x <- factor(c(.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3), ordered = TRUE)
x

#[1] 0.5 1   1.5 2   2.5 3  
#Levels: 0.5 < 1 < 1.5 < 2 < 2.5 < 3
```

You can convert them to numeric and use `ceiling` to combine 0.5 with 1, 1.5 with 2 and so on.

```
y <- factor(ceiling(as.numeric(as.character(x))), ordered = TRUE)
y
#[1] 1 1 2 2 3 3
#Levels: 1 < 2 < 3
```

Another option is to collapse the factor explicitly using `fct_collapse` from `forcats`.

```
y <- forcats::fct_collapse(x, "1" = c("0.5", "1"), 
                              "2" = c("1.5", "2"), 
                              "3" = c("2.5", "3"))
```